# Find and remove multi line sections in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following in Notepad++

```
edit "apple"
    set price 10
edit "pear"
    set price 12
edit "orange"
    set price 10
edit "cherry"
edit "plum"
edit "grapes"
    set price 10
edit "peach"
edit "mango"
    set price 10
```

I would like to remove the lines that don't contain a price; how can I do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^edit.+\R(?!^\h+set price)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  edit            # literally
  .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
  \R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  (?!             # negative lookahead, make we haven't after:
    ^               # beginning of line
    \h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    set price       # literally
  )               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Superb Toto, that's exactly the result I'm after! Thanks for a clear and swift response

Comment: @Ad-: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)